# AngularJS: ui-router secured states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, angular-ui-router

I have one main controller for my app - `AppCtrl` and use ui-router. How can I make secured states?

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    var authorization = toState.data.authorization;

    if(!Security.isAuthenticated() && authorization != false)
        $location.path('/login');
});
```

For example I want to make `books` and `authors` states secured, and `login` state not secured.

```
.state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: /**/,
                controller: /**/,
                data: {
                    authorization: false
                }
            })
.state('books', {
                url: '/books',
                templateUrl: /**/,
                controller: /**/,
                data: {
                    authorization: true
                }
            })
.state('authors', {
                url: '/authors',
                templateUrl: /**/,
                controller: /**/,
                data: {
                    authorization: true
                }
            })
```

`Security.isAuthenticated()` function returns boolean. When I open `/books` everything works perfectly, page are being redirected to `/login`, when after redirecting I open `/authors`, page loads and it's content are shown, but browser's url is `/login`, so page being redirected, but somehow it's content are shown.

Comment: This example might be also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication

Answer (score 3):

Figured out that I have to prevent opening next route, and go to `login` state. Made some changes and all works perfectly.

```
if (!Security.isAuthenticated() && authorization != false){
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
```

Comment: Looks neat. May I ask where you put the if (!Security.isAuthenticated()... block ?

Comment: Sorry. Just saw now you have it with the rootScope state change handler.

Comment: I still wonder how to have it in my multiple modules application. In my case I need to have my rootScope in a module utilsModule.run( or in the app.run(. But then no way to reference the $state.current.data.securedRoute route data.

Comment: I would also be interested in alternatives to the `.run()` method.